# How to retrieve a set of table data in SQL?

Tags: java, sql, mysql

I want to ask a question about the SQL. I have the following table.

```
Name Phone
 a    1
 b    2
 c    3
 d    4
 e    5
```

I have an ArrayList(java) which contains the [a,b,c,d,e]. Is it possible to put the ArrayList into the mySQL statement to retrieve the all the phone numbers? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an IN clause for all the names and map the result set to your data:

```
SELECT Name, Phone FROM Numbers WHERE Name IN ('a','b','c','d','e')
```

I'm sure there are already libraries that do the needed work for you. You could start at http://www.hibernate.org/ with your research.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a direct way to do this.
But you have the following options:

1. You can use the IN clause. Create the IN clause dynamically by looping over the list and creating a string. Note: Oracle limits the number of entries in the IN clause to 1000.
2. You can insert the values into a (temp) table and use this table in your SQL, in a IN clause or as a JOIN (I prefer the join)
3. You can have a PL/SQL stored procedure that takes in a (oracle) Array as parameter. And loop through this array in the stored proc. See [this](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:2229003488805497%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:712625135727) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

you have to create your own statement per java.
iterate over the arraylist and add every string element to the statement.